# Duplicate last value when I use implode()

Tags: php, duplicates, implode

I am facing a problem with php `implode()` function. It is strangely duplicating the last element if the array. Here is an example to explain better:

```
$arr = array('One', 'Two');

// Then...
$str = implode(' - ', $arr);

// Outputs: One - Two - Two
```

No element has been added to or removed from the array. I tried `array_unique` but there are only unique elements.

Thanks in advance.

### Edited

Here is a bit of my code:

```
(isset($this->_title)) OR $this->_title = $this->__guess_title();
// Here $this->_title = 'Welcome'

(is_array($this->_title)) OR $this->_title = array($this->_title);
// Now $this->_title = array('Welcome')

$this->_title = apply_filters('the_title', $this->_title);
// The filter added site name, so the title array is
// array('Welcome', 'SiteName')

// $this->_title_sep = ' - ';
$this->_title = implode($this->_title_sep, $this->_title);

return $this->_title;
// Outputs: Welcome - SiteName - SiteName
```

Here is how I added the filter:

```
// $title is an array, so I add site_name to it and return it.
add_filter('the_title', function( $title ) {
    $title[] = option('site_name');
    return $title;
});
```

[Here](https://prnt.sc/hk45hm) is the array, and [Here](https://prnt.sc/hk45ni) is after implode (screenshots).

Comment: Not with your code as posted here

Comment: the code shown _does not_ output one-two-two (yes, I even tested it...). So there's obviously code missing here.

Comment: I edited and Added a bit of my code.

Comment: you've done a var_dump (or a print_r) after `apply_filters` (or straight before `implode`) with that output: `array('Welcome', 'SiteName')`?

Comment: my guess is `apply_filters()` is adding the extra item...

Comment: print_d before and after the implode I added screenshots. @Jeff, I thought of that and checked with print_d, but no, that's not what it is causing the issue.

Comment: var_dump gave this: `array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Welcome" [1]=> string(7) "ESchool" }`

Comment: still, there is code missing, so we can't answer. The problem is _not_ in the shown code. Please add _where_ you check the output, add the function `apply_filters()`,.. - Right now it's not reproduceable. It's working as it is shown here.

Comment: ok, now we at least know, that you are using and working with wordpress. I don't know how these methods (add_filter, apply_filter) work. So I'm out.

Comment: Not WordPress. CodeIgniter. I created my own theme library that uses the same mechanism that WordPress uses. And I found the issue, I appended the site name twice in another method. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Instead of that second line that uses `OR`, I recommend `$this->_title ??= (array) $this->__guess_title();` in your first line.  It will leave a declared `$this->_title` value unchanged or it will populate the undeclared object as an array-type value meaning: even if `$this->__guess_title()` is a string, it will be converted to a single-element string.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$arr = array('One', 'Two');
$str = implode(' - ', $arr);
echo $str;
?>

//Output is -> One - Two

The code works perfect and it doesn't display "One - Two - Two". I have tested it also and there's no duplicate for the last element.
```

Comment: It obviously doesn't, tested separately, it works just fine. Check my screenshots at the bottom of my question.

Comment: please provide more detail to your answer rather than just pasting the code it is a good practice to point out the mistake in the OP first and then provide a solution